# Views query alter add grouping

Tags: views, 8

Can anyone please help me how to add/alter/remove aggregate options like count/sum/average etc. along with groupings using `hook_views_query_alter` in Drupal 8. I cant seem to find a suitable example.

Thanks
BR/Pratip

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why people down-voted my question. It might have been a little silly to ask if there's a way to alter the group by of a views query using `hook_views_query_alter` because I think aggregation is actually a part of the base query and not views. So instead of using `hook_views_query_alter` we need to use `hook_query_alter`.

Ex.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_alter().
 */
function my_module_query_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->getMetaData('view') && $query->getMetaData('view')->id() === 'my_view') {
    $group_by =& $query->getGroupBy();
    unset($group_by['users_field_data.uid']);
  }
}
```

There are a lot of other memeber function that you can check out like `$query->groupBy('field_name)` that can add another group by clause and so on...

Still not sure why it was down-voted, but I'm sure this might help someone some someday like me.